# How to make a custom javascript function but include a dot

Tags: javascript

How can I custom make my function but have a dot in it like `web.ask("how to...")`

Please help me I'm working on web development

Comment: functions that need a dot to run are called Method. your question should be *"how to create a method?"*.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to wrap it in a containing object.

```js
const web = {
  ask(value) {
    console.log(value);
  }
};

web.ask("how to ...")
```

You can [learn more about objects here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).